# Caching of displayed images in Silverlight/Windows Phone app

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

My app shows a list (`LongListSelector` to be precise) with text and `Image`s. For the images, I currently bind the `Source` attribute to an HTTP URL provided by the model class, which works without problems. However, I am now asking myself, if this strategy is generally advisable with regards to data transfer:

1. Does the framework perform any caching of the downloaded images?
2. If so, how about the scope of the caching? (runtime of the app, or even longer?)
3. If not, is there any existing mechanism, pattern or recommendation, on how to perform caching in such a case?

Comment: [This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcreateoptions(v=vs.95).aspx) provides some information about image caching in Silverlight. There are also a few questions on SO about image caching, especially about how to prevent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Framework performs only caching in memory, so after app restart cache will be cleared
2. runtime only
3. I have got a solution for you. It is [JetImageLoader](https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/jet-image-loader), I created it for application, where we need to load, cache and show big amount of logos, icons and so on.

It can be used as binding converter, so *you should not even change your code! Just update your XAMLs!*

Please, check out [samples in repository](https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/jet-image-loader), you'll love it ;)

**Features:**

- Caching on disk
- Caching in memory
- Fully asynchronous
- Available as binding converter or programmatically from your code
- Fully open source, fork and improve it!

Here is the example:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl, Converter={StaticResource MyAppJetImageLoaderConverter}}"/>
```

P.S. I am sorry, that I copying my answer from another questions, but image caching on windows phone is huge problem and I want to share my solution, so everybody can use it and improve for developers community

Comment: Wow, that sounds really promising! I haven solved the caching problem in my app yet, so this comes very handy. I'll let you know about my experience.

Comment: Glad to hear, enjoy ;)

Comment: Works like a charm and took me not even ten minutes to integrate. Great job, thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, if you want to improve it, just email me or create an issue on the github repo